# $\overline {A}\subseteq \overline {A\cup B}$

Tags: general-topology

I know $\overline {A}\subseteq \overline {A\cup B}$, because $\overline {A\cup B}$ is closed.
Is there a proof for that or is it just a definition thing?

Comment: Could you be more specific about the "definition thing"? Which definitions are you familiar with and supposed to use, in your question? There is a definition of "closure" and that definition could be used to provide a proof. But, there are alternative (and equivalent) definitions of closure, so the proof will depend on the definition that you start with, and different books start with somewhat different forms of the definition of closure. One definition "adds" all limit points (involves use of neighborhoods), another definition intersects all closed sets containing the given set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\overline{A\cup B}$ is closed and $A\subset A\cup B\subset\overline{A\cup B}$, we have$$\overline A\subset\overline{\overline{A\cup B}}=\overline{A\cup B}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Of course there is a proof.

$A \subset \overline{A \cup B}$ follows immediately, right?

What other elements are in $\overline A$ and what condition do they satisfy? Can you show that such condition can also be satisfied with the points in $\overline{A\cup B}$?